# <c:url> tag analog in Play framework

Tags: java, url, tags, playframework

Is there any analog of jstl `url` tag, which can be used to generate valid URL, independently of current template location or application location.

For example, `#{a @Application.logout()}Disconnect#{/a}` simply generate `/application/logout` URL.

But i'm looking for a tag that will generate me `/logout` URL. This url will point to `Application.logout()` method in `routes` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. just realized why this tag generate `/application/logout` instead of `logout`. It's because of this in routes file

```
# Catch all
*   /{controller}/{action}    {controller}.{action}
```

If i delete it or move below logout defenition, everything works fine

Comment: Keep in mind that the routes file is processed like a script by Play, order matters. I also would recommend to comment that entry, as it opens the door to some security issues.

Comment: Always ensure that the catch-all route is the last route in your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
<a href="@Application.logout()}">Logout</a>
```

Then play will generate your url relatively for you. You can also use:

```
<a href="@@Application.logout()}">Logout</a>
```

to generate absolute urls.
If you want to customize the url to be used go to the routes file and add e.g

```
/logout                   Application.logout
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write @Application.logout() to get the URL.

In your case:

```
<a href="@Application.logout()}">Logout</a>
```